# perl DBI execute doesn't recognize '?'

Tags: database, perl, postgresql, dbd, dbd-pg

I have this code:

```
if($update[$entity_id])
{
    my $sql = "UPDATE cache SET date = '?', value = '?' WHERE item_id = ? AND level = ? AND type = ?;";
}
else
{
    my $sql = "INSERT INTO cache (date, value, item_id, level, type) VALUES ('?','?',?,?,?);";
}
my $db = $self->{dbh}->prepare(q{$sql}) or die ("unable to prepare");
$db->execute(time2str("%Y-%m-%d %X", time), $stored, $entity_id, 'entity', 'variance');
```

But when it want to run the update I get this error:

> DBD::Pg::st execute failed : called with 5 bind variables when 0 are needed.

Why?

Comment: in the $stored variable is text, which can contain space, in the date there is also one so it's needed.

Comment: No, you don't need it. That's the point of placeholders.

Comment: Ok, I removed them, but still the same error...

Comment: No, either you did not remove them, or you are not getting the same error. Show code.

Comment: Remove the q{} from `->execute(q{$sql})` also. What do you think `q{...}` does?

Comment: Also, see DBI docs, and use RaiseError. You then do not need to do 'or die ...' on DBI methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had turned on strict and/or warnings, you would see what your problem is.

You're writing

```
if (...) {
    my $sql = ...;
} else {
    my $sql = ...;
}
execute($sql);
```

Which means that the `$sql` variables that you declare in the `if` branches *aren't in scope* and you're trying to execute completely empty SQL.

Comment: Of course, that was the biggest problem. But all answer was helpfull, thank you for all

Answer (score 6):

You're preparing literal `'$sql'`, but that is not your only problem, lexical `$sql` variables go out of scope outside `{}`.

Try,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
#...

my $sql;
if($update[$entity_id])
{
    $sql = "UPDATE cache SET date = ?, value = ? WHERE item_id = ? AND level = ? AND type = ?";
}
else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cache (date, value, item_id, level, type) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
}
my $st = $self->{dbh}->prepare($sql) or die ("unable to prepare");
$st->execute(time2str("%Y-%m-%d %X", time), $stored, $entity_id, 'entity', 'variance');
```